How to read external config file in Django and have it available everywhere
I want to define an external config file, for example, in Yaml.  How can I read it in once at initialization and then have it available everywhere, without having to re-read the file each time?
For example, if I put this in apps.py
def ready(self)
    config = yaml.safe_load(open("config.yml"))

How do I reference this from, for example, views.py

You can upload your file to the settings and then access it from everywhere.
Change in settings.py:
# settings.py
BASE_URL = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
...
MY_YAML = yaml.safe_load((BASE_URL / 'config.yml').read_text())
...

After that, you will be able to refer to it from everywhere in project:
# somethere in project xyz.py
from django.conf import settings
...
yaml = settings.MY_YAML
...


This seems like a reasonable solution. Will you add an example how you would use it?

i add it, i hope it is clear
